# How to adjust height and formatting of rows in Bokeh DataTable

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, datatable, bokeh

I'm trying to adjust the font-size of the title and cells and pop-up message of a bokeh DataTable.
When doing so using the HTMLTamplateFormatter I can get the font-size to increase, however, I do not know how to increase the height of a row.

Also I have no clue how to adjust the formatting/height of the top/title cell of the column.

I was able to make the title bold using the information provided at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954997/python-bokeh-datatable-cells-styling) issue. Is there a similar piece of code I could use to increase the font-size.

When hovering a cell I want to show some information, I would also like to format this, is that possible? And if so how?

This is a minimal example of what I currently have:

```
import pandas

from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, TableColumn, DataTable)
from bokeh.models.widgets import HTMLTemplateFormatter
from bokeh.io import show


data = pandas.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     "y": [200, 3, 4, 5]})
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

columns = []

# column 1 with bold title: x and 200% font-size
template200 = """
<div title="<%= x %>" style="font-size: 200%">
<%= value %>
</div>
"""
htmltemplateformatter200 = HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template200)
col = "x"
title = "<b>%s</b>" % col
columns.append(TableColumn(field=col, title=title,
                           width=50, editor=None,
                           formatter=htmltemplateformatter200))

# column 2 with normal title: y and 400% font-size

template400 = """
<div title="<%= x %>" style="font-size: 400%">
<%= value %>
</div>
"""
htmltemplateformatter400 = HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template400)
col = "y"
columns.append(TableColumn(field=col, title=col,
                           width=50, editor=None,
                           formatter=htmltemplateformatter400))

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, row_headers=False,
                       sortable=False)

show(data_table)
```

This code will make the text in the table cell bigger. However, when I change the size to 400% the text is larger than the height of the row can visualize.

Could anyone help me with this?

Cheers,
Dave

**First edit:**

To show what I want to be able to do:

[image: Table where row heights are adapted to text size]

In my case I think I would only need a single row height since I want all the font-sizes to be the same.

**Second edit:**

After the reply of Okonomiyaki I looked at my code again and came up with the following solution:

main.py:

```
import pandas

from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, TableColumn, DataTable)
from bokeh.models.widgets import HTMLTemplateFormatter
from bokeh.io import curdoc


data = pandas.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4],
                        "y": [200, 3, 4, 5]})
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

columns = []

# column 1 with bold title: x and 20px font-size
template200 = """
<div title="<%= x %>" style="font-size: 20px;">
<%= value %>
</div>
"""
htmltemplateformatter200 = HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template200)
col = "x"
title = "<b>%s</b>" % col
columns.append(TableColumn(field=col, title=title,
                           width=50, editor=None,
                           formatter=htmltemplateformatter200))


# column 2 with bold title: y and 20px font-size
template400 = """
<div title="<%= y %>" style="font-size: 20px;">
<%= value %>
</div>
"""
htmltemplateformatter400 = HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template400)
col = "y"
columns.append(TableColumn(field=col, title=col,
                           width=50, editor=None,
                           formatter=htmltemplateformatter400))

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, row_headers=False,
                       sortable=False, height=1000, fit_columns=True)

curdoc().add_root(data_table)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
    <style>
      {% include 'jquery-ui.css' %}
      {% include 'styles.css' %}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="content">
      {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    </div>
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
  </body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
.ui-tooltip {
padding: 8px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
max-width: 500px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
opacity: 1;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the solution to just use the HTML formatter? It would likely be easier to use a css sheet. You can change the style of each of the cell divs to increase the size. For the information on hover, do you want the cell contents to change? I think a standalone javascript would be the cleanest way.

Comment: It is not necessary for me to just use the HTML formatter. I'm just not very familiar with HTML/css. Could you perhaps explain how I would be able to add such a css sheet to my bokeh output? I know how to do it when I run it as the code above (using show(), however, how do I add it when using the bokeh server? And how do I incorporate a standalone javascript in my bokeh table?

Comment: ok i will create a minimal example for you. Also in regards to changing row widths, you may want them all to be the same width right? changing an individual row would not look very pleasing

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to be correct. I would like to change the height of the rows. This might differ per row, or at least I would like to have the top row (title row) a different height than the other (data) rows. I'll add an example to show what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So few things, it turns out it is not possible to have variable row heights with a data_table. This is a restriction set by the underlying Js library - Slick Grid.

https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/cg01WWfpdhw
Some discussion relevant to bokeh here.

You can however easily have variable styles on each row, and this can be set within python. Having the text/styles change is easier done with an external css sheet - although could be done within the HTML formatter, but quite messily.

Create the following app structure: (to run in command prompt type `bokeh serve --show myapp`)

```
myapp
   |
   +---main.py
   |---templates
           +---index.html
           +---styles.css
```

**main.py**  (contained within myapp directory) :

```
import pandas

from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, TableColumn, DataTable)
from bokeh.models.widgets import HTMLTemplateFormatter
from bokeh.io import show, curdoc


x0 = [1,"8px", "red", "bold", "hover 1"]
x1 = [2,"10px", "blue", "italic", "hover 2"]
x2 = [3,"12px", "green", "bold", "hover 3"]
x3 = [4,"14px", "orange", "strong", "hover 4"]
x = [x0,x1,x2,x3]
data = pandas.DataFrame({"x": x,
                     "y": [200, 3, 4, 5]})
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

columns = []

# now in the formatter value[0] = original x value
# value[1] = desired font size
# value[2] = desired font color
# value[3] = desired font style
# value[4] = text to display on hover
# you could feed in any styles you want, or do it externally via css + js
template200 = """
<div title="<%= x %>" style="font-size: <%= value[1]%> ; 
color: <%=value[2]%>; font-weight:<%=value[3] %>;" >
<div class = "parent_div"> 
<span class="nonhover"> <%= value[0] %> </span>
<span class= "cell_hover"><%= value[4]%></span> </div>
</div>
"""
htmltemplateformatter200 = HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template200)
col = "x"
title = "<b>%s</b>" % col
columns.append(TableColumn(field=col, title=title,
                           width=50, editor=None,
                           formatter=htmltemplateformatter200))

# column 2 with normal title: y and 400% font-size

template400 = """
<div title="<%= x %>" style="font-size: 20px;">
<%= value %>
</div>
"""
htmltemplateformatter400 = HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template400)
col = "y"
columns.append(TableColumn(field=col, title=col,
                           width=50, editor=None,
                           formatter=htmltemplateformatter400))

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, row_headers=False,
                       sortable=False,height = 1000, fit_columns=True)

curdoc().add_root(data_table)
```

**styles.css** (contained within directory templates)
Basically you have two spans within a div. When you hover over them, one has the display property set to none - therefore not visible. The other span which is previously not visible then has its display set to inline, becoming visible. You can change the style of the hover over text through this.

Also note because both of the spans are contained within the very outer div which has the styles set through python, both the hover and default text have the same css style properties.

```
.nonhover{
display: inline;
}

.cell_hover{
display: none;
background: yellow;
}

.parent_div:hover .nonhover{
display: none;
}

.parent_div:hover .cell_hover{
display: inline;
background: yellow;
}
```

**index.html** (contained within directory templates)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
    <style>
      {% include 'styles.css' %}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="content">
      {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    </div>
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that still helps.

Comment: Thank you for your example and effort :) I'm very gratefull. It helped me a lot. In your answer you mention: # you could feed in any styles you want, or do it externally via css + js
I'm not sure how to include additional js. I'm not familiar with this at all. So when I have a js-file and when I try to do this: <script src="file:///path_to_files/jquery-ui.js"></script> I get the message: 
Not allowed to load local resource.
Without bokeh, I was able to refer to local files and open the html. How does this work?

Comment: If your script is in the same folder as index.html you can insert this in the head of the html file: <script> {% include 'code.js' %}</script>. Not entirely sure how to specify an arbitrary path though unfortunately. If the answer helped please upvote and mark as correct, thanks.